# Bitnami Django Stack not working with React

Tags: django, reactjs, webpack-dev-server, bitnami

I have deployed a `Django` application using Bitnami's Django Stack application. In my application, I'm using `React` for some of my views and loading them into my Django template via `{% load render_bundle from webpack_loader %}`. However, when trying to access my website, the browser stalls and nothing is loaded (I assume that the `webpack_loader` has something to do with it.

Any tips for debugging or does anyone have a solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Bitnami Django Stack uses `mod_wsgi` to deploy Python applications using Apache as Web Server. Therefore, you will find the Django logs under the Apache Log Directory:

```
/installdir/apache2/logs/
```

Please note that you need to substitute `installdir` with the path to the directory where you installed the Bitnami Django Stack.

I hope it helps you to debug your error.